# Cannot Send Object from ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

sirs. I am trying understand ExpressJS. I want to send simple object from express server but it just logs cannot get on screen.

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("middleware");
  const error = true;

  if (error) {
    next();
  }
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(400).json({ error: "error description" });
});
```

In this code i simulated if error happens send object but it just sends cannot get. In POSTMAN body section, i just see html code with cannot get. What happening here? Can you please explain me?

In POSTMAN i can just get this HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error handler is never reached, because there is no error passed to the next() function. Because the first route handler doesn´t send a response, you get 'Cannot GET /'.

From the [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

> For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route
> handlers and middleware, you must pass them to the next() function,
> where Express will catch and process them.

Just pass the error to the next() function, and your code will work as expected.
In your example:

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("middleware");
  const error = new Error('bad things just happened');

  if (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(400).json({ error: "error description" });
});
```